# How do I remove blank lines from files?

Tags: text-processing

I have a file (hosts) with some lines without content, how do I remove that lines without content?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Using sed

Type the following command:

```
sed '/^$/d' input.txt > output.txt
```

#### Using grep

Type the following command:

```
grep -v '^$' input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 8):

Many ways:

1. Use `sed` and edit the file in place.

   ```
   sudo sed -i -rn '/\S/p' /etc/hosts
   ```
2. Same, but with Perl:

   ```
   sudo perl -i -ne 'print if /\S/' /etc/hosts
   ```
3. Newer versions of GNU `awk`, in place again:

   ```
   sudo awk -i inplace '/\S/' file
   ```

All of the above solutions will also remove lines that contain nothing but whitespace. If you only want to remove empty lines, and leave lines that contain spaces or tabs etc, change the `/\S/` to `/^$/` in all of the above examples.

Comment: for the sake of completeness, you can also say `grep -v '.' file`.

Comment: @fedorqui indeed, but I think you meant `grep '.' file`, we want to remove empty lines, not keep them.

Comment: +1, however the `-r` switch on the `sed` command is not really needed there since you're not taking advantage of `ERE`-specific syntax

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the other commands will fail to remove blank lines if the lines contain a blank space. The following will remove all blank lines including lines that contain only blank spaces.

```
grep -v '^[[:space:]]*$' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Is a nice solutions, in xml files for example is possible to have spaces. A similar solution with sed can be: "sed '/^\s*$/d' input.txt > output.txt"

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc v/./d -cx hosts
```

1. `/./` find non blank lines
2. `v` invert selection
3. `d` delete
4. `x` save and close

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the default Ubuntu Text Editor (gedit) by:

- Press `Ctrl`+`H` to open Find and Replace
- In the 'Find' box, enter `\n\n` which signifies two new lines without text in-between them.
- In the 'Replace' box, enter `\n`
- Click 'Replace All'

If the text file was produced in windows, you may want to try `\r\n`.